# Custom repository adapter in clustered environment

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-portal

I'm planning to use a Custom Repository to manage security in Websphere Portal V7. According to [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/zones/portal/proddoc/dw-w-userrepository/index.html), to get this working I need to edit some configuration files in the Server, run some commands and copy some JARS.

The article refers to a single server, but I'm not sure how to proceed in Production Environment, where there is a Cluster of two Websphere Portal Servers. Do I need to replicate all the steps on every server, or only in the Deployment Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a detailled procedure for installing a Custom User Registry in WebSphere Portal in a Clustered Environment. First, you follow this procedure in your main node: [Creating and configuring stand-alone repositories](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/7.0.0/doc/en_us/pt700abd001/html-wrapper-accessible.html#add_cur_snd).

Then this procedure needs to be followed in your secondary node: [Enabling LDAP security after cluster creation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20WebSphere%20Portal%207%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Enabling_LDAP_security_after_cluster_creation_wp7&content=pdcontent).

All the Links are form IBM Documentation, for WPS V7.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying the jar to AppServer/lib must be done for each cluster members, this directory is not distributed by the dmgr. The jar need to be put on each cluster member so it can have it in its classpath.

Configuration changes to VMM can be made on the dmgr only, VMM configuration is cell scoped and is distributed by the dmgr (configuration stored under /config/cells//wim

I did not setup such solutions for Portal, but for WAS its basically what you need to do.